# Конфликт datetimepicker и MultiDatesPicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Проблема в том, что на админ-панели сайта подключена библиотека datetimepicker и никак нельзя её отключить. Нужно реализовать выбор несколько дат, а в этом плагине нет этой функции. Я нашел http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/, но после подключения выдает ошибки:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_hideDatepicker' of undefined` и `jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js:165 Uncaught TypeError: $this.datepicker is not a function`

`$.noConflict();` не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было подключить сам Jquery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```